# How do I get Adob Reader to allow my interactive PDF to be saved for e-mail?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I made a Questionnaire in Indesign CS6 and have the newest version of Adobe Reader.  I'm trying to test it out but the bar at the top of the screen says that the information put into the form can't be saved so it should be printed out if you want a record.  So when I try to attach to an email or use a submit button it just doesn't work because it's not allowed.  How do I change this?  I've been back and forth through both Indesign and Adobe Reader and I don't see anything that allows that.  Is that something I have to set in Acrobat Pro?  How can this be resolved?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to save the results as a new PDF or are you trying to send the results in an email using a button on the PDF?

Comment: I was trying to do both and neither worked.  If possible I'd prefer to use the submit button to email the answers.  I just want it to be as easy as possible for my clients.

Comment: This might be useful [Enable Reader users to save form data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7e0d.w.html).

Comment: @AndrewH: That article is pretty much outdated; Reader XI and newer do no longer need Extended Rights for saving, and with Acrobat DC, that (unenforceable) limit of 500 uses has apparently been lifted as well.

Comment: @Max Wyss, while that's true, you can't assume that recipients of the form have Reader XI+. I actually didn't know that this "feature" was removed in XI because my company still has Reader 9 on all our machines.

Comment: @Scribblemacher: It is important to have an idea of which tools the end users are using; that's part of the analysis process. Change of topic: unless there are really, really, good reasons for keeping Reader 9, it is strongly recommended to upgrade to a newer version. Reader 9 has been past its end of support life more than a year ago, and there will not be any support or security updates from Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Javascript inside a PDF and make the form inside the PDF make an HTTP call to a web-service.
This way the only requirement for your client is having an internet connection.

See the Acrobat SDK: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJSPreface%2FJS_API_AcroJSPreface.htm